# SELECT de Header e Itens de um XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, select

Olá,

Como posso fazer um select de um `XML` com header e itens?

Eu tenho isso:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = CONVERT(XML,'
<ROOT v="2.15.0">
  <LOTEANIH APP="00B1" LOTE="1">
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="10" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="11" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="12" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="13" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="14" />
  </LOTEANIH>
  <LOTEANIH APP="XB8F" LOTE="1">
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="1" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="2" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="3" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="4" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="5" />
  </LOTEANIH>
</ROOT>');
```

Estou selecionando desta maneira (sei que está errado :/):

```
WITH CTe AS (
    SELECT
         h.value('@APP', 'varchar(4)') AS APP_ID
        ,h.value('@LOTE', 'int') AS NRO_LOTE
        ,i.value('@ANIMAL', 'int') AS ANIMAL
    FROM @XML.nodes('/ROOT/LOTEANIH') AS header(h)
        CROSS APPLY @XML.nodes('/ROOT/LOTEANIH/LOTEANIM') AS child(i)
)
SELECT * FROM CTe
```

E estou tendo isso de retorno:
[image: Retorno]

Enquanto eu procuro/preciso desse retorno (separado igual ao xml):
[image: Correto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só troquei a XQuery do `@APP` e do `@LOTE`. O resto tá tudo quase igual.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = CONVERT(XML,'
<ROOT v="2.15.0">
  <LOTEANIH APP="00B1" LOTE="1">
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="10" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="11" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="12" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="13" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="14" />
</LOTEANIH>
<LOTEANIH APP="XB8F" LOTE="1">
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="1" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="2" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="3" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="4" />
    <LOTEANIM ANIMAL="5" />
</LOTEANIH>
</ROOT>');


select x.value('../@APP', 'VARCHAR(4)'),
       x.value('../@LOTE', 'INT'),
       x.value('./@ANIMAL', 'INT')
from @XML.nodes('/ROOT/LOTEANIH/LOTEANIM') h(x);
```